# Was the misspelling of the HTTP field name Referer intentional?

Tags: http, specifications, misspelling

I read recently (I can't recall where, or I'd return to that source) that the misspelling of HTTP header field name Referer in the specification was intentional.  Is that accurate?  If so, why?

Comment: Wikipedia has an explanation with references that it was not on purpose (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Phillip Hallam-Baker and Roy Fielding are responsible for it. By the time they realized it was incorrect, too many people were using it.

Now, Phillip [jokes about getting the Oxford Dictionary to recognize his spelling](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.folklore.computers/msg/e17f380d477d0526?hl=en&dmode=source&safe=on&pli=1&safe=on):

> Its like when I did the referer field.
> I got nothing but grief for my choice
> of spelling. I am now attempting to
> get the spelling corrected in the OED
> since my spelling is used several
> billion times a minute more than
> theirs.

Roy also joked about the fact that the UNIX `spell` command [didn't recognize any spelling of it](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg-old/1995JanApr/0107.html):

> `>` Has anyone else noticed that the HTTP header "Referer:" is spelled
> wrong?
>
> That's okay, neither one (referer or
> referrer) is understood by "spell"
> anyway.  I say we should just blame it
> on France.  ;-)

Info taken from [HTTP_REFERER Origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer#Etymology) Wikipedia article.

Comment: It's not a misspelling; it's an _optimization_. By leaving out the redundant 'R' in the header name, he's probably reduced many terabytes of bandwidth usage over the years. =P

Comment: If that's the case it should be the `R:` header.

Comment: My brain hates typos. As much as Hallam-Baker jokes about trying to get his version in the dictionary, the bottom line is that he didn't know how to spell. So damned annoying!

Comment: You shouldn't let typos get under your skin, @ChuckLeButt, especially in our line of work. Remember, nerve cells don't regenerate very much or very fast. 
Referer: https://askabiologist.asu.edu/regeneration

Comment: @PaulMark In our line of work a typo means the difference between a running system and a crashed one X-)

Answer (score 7):

I believe it was a mistake that was only picked up after release, at that point it was too late to change it and a lot of dependencies already existed.

a wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) to (semi) prove it :)

Comment: Yea, but why is "hello" misspelled in SMTP?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that `HELO` in SMTP was a throwback to ARPANET but I can't find any citations for that, so take it with a boulder of salt.

Comment: I believe you misspelled "prove" :)

Comment: Spelling it `HELO` is probably to fit a 4-character limit for command names. (Just like with FTP commands.)