# How do I find the a referring sites URL in node?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, express

How do I find the a referring sites URL in node?

I'm using express, would I find this in the headers on connect or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you mean how do you get it when running an express server, then it's done using the [header](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#req.header%28%29) method on your request:

```
req.headers.referer;
// => "http://google.com"
```

Comment: It should be `req.headers['referer']`.

Comment: Another option: req.headers.referer

Comment: None of this works for me, I get `undefined`. This is in express router.

Answer (score 137):

In express 4.x:

```
req.get('Referrer')
```

This will also check [both spellings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3087656/179015) of referrer so you do not have to do:

```
 req.headers.referrer || req.headers.referer
```

Here is the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.get)

Comment: HTTP specs's header name is `Referer` and I find `req.get('Referrer')` and `req.get('Referer')` get the same result

Answer (score 2):

Express 5.0-alpha2 with new JS features.

```
const referrer = req.get('Referer') ?? req.get('Referrer') ?? null;
```

I am checking for both spelling as weirdly they can happen sometimes, but it should be super rare.

weirdly just access headers object didn't work for me. It's possible it's only issue with my alpha, but leaving it here for others.

For people having undefined / null

First of all: Referer is not always there. Actually, it's very often not there so make sure you have a fallback. There's a lot of reasons. It can be because someone visited link directly, but it can be also due to privacy settings, browser extensions etc.

`Referer` can also be also easily spoofed, so using it as a security measure is not really great.

For those cases where it's not empty it can be pretty useful for getting more info about users. Just remember to keep fallback.