# How to get "HTTP_REFERER" with NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-referer

A way to get `HTTP_REFERER` , We can use `document.referrer` in browser side javascript .
But how can we get it in NodeJS ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting HTTP headers with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922842/getting-http-headers-with-node-js)

Comment: Take a look to req.headers / req.header('Referer')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the a referring sites URL in node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237262/how-do-i-find-the-a-referring-sites-url-in-node)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can get it by...

```
req.headers.referer
```

in...

```
var http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
...
}
```

Comment: @Shay, Isn't this the same thing in JavaScript?

Comment: @ajkochanowicz yes, but better convention

Comment: I would add that some browsers send referer (like chrome) and some referrer (like Safari on OSx)

Comment: Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/28238737/205832 instead if you use Express 4.x.

Comment: This seems to no longer be the case ... where did it move to? There's no .headers on the IncomingMessage anywhere?