# How to view what someone was looking at before viewing my website

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, web, firewall

I was wondering if you could view the previous website someone was looking at using some sort of workaround like browser.history.go.back.

I am working on a project. Just to see how much information you could collect on someone just by going to a website.

Comment: You can't, this would be an incredibly huge privacy violation.

Comment: If they click on a link to get to your website you can get the original URL from the `Referer` header.

Comment: How Would They Do This?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579994/how-to-get-http-referer-with-nodejs