# Classic ASP - mimic Back browser button

Tags: asp-classic

What is the best way to have a button mimic the "Back" browser button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the browser side javascript call history.back.

```
window.history.back()
```

Answer (score 3):

`<a href="<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")%>">Back</a>`

Comment: This has to be the best answer for a question which specifies Classic ASP :)

Comment: I like it better since it can be done server-side only.  JS means you have to hit the client browser before going back.  There are also a few issues with using JS to go back.

Comment: For the ones who are new to ASP: in this case REFERER is spelled incorrectly (should be referrer) but this is how it was defined. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087626/was-the-misspelling-of-the-http-field-name-referer-intentional