# Get request URL in Firebase Cloud function

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have two Angular applications that are connecting to the same Firebase/Firestore instance:

- https://admin.myapp.com
- https://myapp.com

I have implemented Firebase Cloud Functions with Express, but would like to conditionally manipulate the data being returned based on which applications is making the request. I have tried using `req.get('origin')` to detect the origin of the request, but that always returns the URL provided by the Firebase Cloud (cloudfunctions.net/).

Can I access this information another way?

Comment: It would appear that `req.get('referrer')` does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the 'Referer' HTTP request header field.

To access it you can do either:

```js
req.get('Referrer')
req.get('Referer')
req.headers.referer
req.headers.referrer
```

It checks for [both spelling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087626/was-the-misspelling-of-the-http-field-name-referer-intentional/3087656#3087656), there is no need to test which is being passed.